# Could you may be point us to the right person? Is this sentence wrong?

Tags: grammar

Could you may be point us to the right person?   Is this sentence wrong?

Comment: "may be" should be "maybe," but I can't tell if that is the question you have or just a typo. "Could you" and "Can you" have different technical meanings, but in conversational English "could" is likely to be intended and interpreted as slightly more formal and therefore as more of a request than "can" and certainly more than the flavors of ordering "please point me" and "point me."

Comment: Hi adi, welcome to EL&U. Regrettably, I'm flagging this question for closure: proofreading questions ("Is this correct?", "Is there a better way to write this passage?") are off-topic unless a specific source of concern in the text is clearly identified and you include the research you've done. For further guidance, see [ask] and take the EL&U **[Tour]**. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I would remove the "may be" (or "maybe") entirely, leaving the sentence as follows:

> Could you point us to the right person?

The additional uncertainties seem unnecessary and wouldn't be much different than chaining a bunch of them together in a sentence like this:

> Could you, maybe, by any chance, perhaps, point us to the right person?